# How does cardIO create the extra activity or View?

Tags: android, android-studio

The basic app that uses card.IO has only one activity, the `MainActivity`. 
When a specific button is clicked, that button calls another activity that does not have a java file or XML file in android studio but is only specified in the manifest like this:
I have noticed other apps using this method of creating new activities but I have not figured out how such activities get created. Does anyone know how they are created?
Here is the [gitHub link](https://github.com/johnsanspatrick/cardio/tree/master/CardIO/app/src).
as you can see there is only one java file and XML layout file for the `MainActivity`. However once the button is clicked, this starts a new activity requiring the entry of card details. This other activity is only specified in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency is pulled in from the [gradle build file](https://github.com/johnsanspatrick/cardio/blob/master/CardIO/app/build.gradle#L29) which then downloads the card.io library. The library is where you can find all the activities [here](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source/tree/master/card.io/src/main/java/io/card/payment) that are not found in the linked project.

Gradle is a build tool that android uses to help organize all the tasks associated with building an app.

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I have been looking for